# I get an error in CreateJS: "createjs is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, createjs

I have a problem with `creatJS` I hope you can help.

```
 var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
```

I got this error :

> angular.js:13642 ReferenceError: createjs is not defined. even thought i get the EaselJS in my bower-components.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us the full code please?

Comment: this is my code in the controller :var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
            var image = new createjs.Bitmap("app/common/views/weather/img/windrose.png");
            stage.addChild(image);
            stage.update();

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Usually this is caused by an incorrectly loaded script tag or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem - in my case I added the [createjs-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/createjs-module) npm package for webpack (I use it in the Laravel wabpack mix). It appeared that there was an issue with the scope, so I had to ensure that createjs is global. So you can try to do the following:

1. Install the npm module (in the console)

   ```
   npm install createjs-module --save
   ```
2. Initialize the createjs (in your js file)

   ```
   this.createjs = {};
   ```
3. Make createjs global (in your js file)

   ```
   window.createjs = this.createjs;
   ```
4. Import the module (in your js file)

   ```
   require('createjs-module');
   ```

And now you can use it as usual :)

Reference: [CreateJS GitHub Issues](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/85)

Answer (score 1):

I assume createjs is defined in the window object. To be accessible in angular js you need to make it injectabled like this :

```
  angular.module('myApp', [])
  .constant('createjs', window.createjs)
```

Then you can inject it into your controller for example :

```
controller: function(createjs) {
  var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
}
```

You can also refer to it by using $window :

```
controller: function($window) {
  var stage = new $window.createjs.Stage(canvas);
}
```

Comment: thank you, the problem was that easeljs the library which i use for creatjs was not injected in the bower.json file... so finally i injected the library in the Bower file and it work.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just get some tests on it and i verify if the library EaselJS which is used for createjs is injected but it was not injected in the Bower.json file. so i had to injected manually in the bower.json file and it's working.