# Using createJS in typescript?

Tags: powerbi, createjs

I am attempting to incorporate createJS into a typescript project (a powerbi visual) that I am building.

I have done the following:

1) Installed createJS and typings file using:

`npm install createjs --save` and `npm install --save @types/createjs`

2) Added this line to the the `externalJS` array in `pbiviz.json` : `"node_modules/createjs/builds/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"`

3) Added the path to the typings file to the `files` array in my `tsconfig.ts` file:
`"node_modules/@types/createjs/index.d.ts"`.

Something didn't go right, I'm seeing the following error in my console: 
[image: Error Trace]

This was without actually calling the namespace in my code, if  I attempt to use the namespace then it simply breaks my code without any warnings. My IDE's auto-suggest offers `createjs`implying to me that it was imported properly but still something isn't right.

I think its related to this [thread](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/85) but I don't understand how to implement the solution it typescript. Can anyone help?

My project structure:
[image: structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue is an internal issue. I found a solution that I will not pretend to fully understand.

Starting from scratch, instead of installing the `createjs` package with the `--save` option  I ran

`npm install createjs-module --save` and
`npm install --save @types/createjs`

which is apparently a webpack.

After this I `"node_modules/createjs-module/createjs.js"` in to my `externalJS` array, as well as the appropriate typings file to my `tsconfig.json`.

Credit to [tsveti_iko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551756/7046421)

see also:

[this](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/85)

Comment: Could you please be so kind and *not* post the command `npm install createjs --save` just after the world "install" and in such a way that it is easy to copy? Because I totally over-read the "instead". I know that we should all carefully read but it is so easy to miss. It is just too inviting to just copy paste a command if it is written in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to import createjs(not createjs specific)

This is what I use in my ts classes. For this you have to set compiler options module to system in tsconfig.json. This is what I use. I seems it's not the recommended one. It like an import statement(or maybe more like an include script)

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
```

.ts files using createjs:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/createjs.d.ts"/>
```

The other method is to use import statements along with commonjs. This is the recommended one. I was not able to make it work but didn't try too much because the first method is working.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html